# pb while applying incremental android OTA on pixel

Tags: android, updates

I am building my own AOSP that include full and incremental OTA updates. My device is a google pixel running a 7.1.1.

I can perfectly build android images and generating OTA.
Within the AOSP, my steps are the following one :

- update_api ;
- droid (default target for generating android images) ;
- brillo_update_payload ;
- dist

Then I am generating OTA packages like this:

```
$ ./build/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files dist_output/tardis-target_files.zip ota_update.zip
```

and

```
$ ./build/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files -i PREVIOUS-tardis-target_files.zip dist_output/tardis-target_files.zip incremental_ota_update.zip # make incremental from the older version
```

It works fine for the full OTA, but it failed for the differential one. The logcat I have while applying the OTA is the following one:

> 04-05 08:13:07.156  2407  2421 D AMA.ou.Update: onStatusUpdate: status=3, progression=31.58676%
>
> 04-05 08:13:07.157  2407  2420 D AMA.ou.Update: onStatusUpdate: status=3, progression=32.635754%
>
> 04-05 08:13:07.166  2407  2407 D AMA.ou.UpdateView: Updating progressbar to 26%
>
> 04-05 08:13:07.166  2407  2407 D AMA.ou.UpdateView: Updating progressbar to 27%
>
> 04-05 08:13:07.166  2407  2407 D AMA.ou.UpdateView: Updating progressbar to 28%
>
> 04-05 08:13:07.167  2407  2407 D AMA.ou.UpdateView: Updating progressbar to 29%
>
> 04-05 08:13:07.167  2407  2407 D AMA.ou.UpdateView: Updating progressbar to 30%
>
> 04-05 08:13:07.167  2407  2407 D AMA.ou.UpdateView: Updating progressbar to 31%
>
> 04-05 08:13:07.168  2407  2407 D AMA.ou.UpdateView: Updating progressbar to 32%
>
> 04-05 08:13:08.783   643   643 I update_engine: [0405/081308:INFO:delta_performer.cc(359)] Applying 8991 operations to partition "system"
>
> 04-05 08:13:08.800   643   643 E update_engine: [0405/081308:ERROR:delta_performer.cc(1060)]

The hash of the source data on disk for this operation doesn't match the expected value. This could mean that the delta update payload was targeted for another version, or that the source partition was modified after it was installed, for example, by mounting a filesystem.

> 04-05 08:13:08.800   643   643 E update_engine: [0405/081308:ERROR:delta_performer.cc(1065)] Expected:   sha256|hex = 8F508C72E6E95A3D98EA0B5F3A5D29BADE2224A09930FF479B1B4FE2D7AAAEDA
>
> 04-05 08:13:08.800   643   643 E update_engine: [0405/081308:ERROR:delta_performer.cc(1068)] Calculated: sha256|hex = 6BAA0BB1F6E02DBE752235E0BC7F5DA075340781B78E88BC61214C0DE353E5A6
>
> 04-05 08:13:08.800   643   643 E update_engine: [0405/081308:ERROR:delta_performer.cc(1077)] Operation source (offset:size) in blocks: 129:16
>
> 04-05 08:13:08.800   643   643 E update_engine: [0405/081308:ERROR:delta_performer.cc(1142)] ValidateSourceHash(source_hasher.raw_hash(), operation, error) failed.
>
> 04-05 08:13:08.800   643   643 E update_engine: [0405/081308:ERROR:delta_performer.cc(283)] Failed to perform SOURCE_COPY operation 13, which is the operation 2 in partition "system"
>
> 04-05 08:13:08.800   643   643 E update_engine: [0405/081308:ERROR:download_action.cc(273)] Error 20 in DeltaPerformer's Write method when processing the received payload -- Terminating processing
>
> 04-05 08:13:08.806  1033  1721 D DnsEventListenerService: Logging 100 results for netId 100
>
> 04-05 08:13:08.809   643   643 I update_engine: [0405/081308:INFO:multi_range_http_fetcher.cc(171)] Received transfer terminated.
>
> 04-05 08:13:08.809   643   643 I update_engine: [0405/081308:INFO:multi_range_http_fetcher.cc(123)] TransferEnded w/ code 200
>
> 04-05 08:13:08.809   643   643 I update_engine: [0405/081308:INFO:multi_range_http_fetcher.cc(125)] Terminating.
>
> 04-05 08:13:08.809   643   643 I update_engine: [0405/081308:INFO:action_processor.cc(116)] ActionProcessor: finished DownloadAction with code ErrorCode::kDownloadStateInitializationError
>
> 04-05 08:13:08.809   643   643 I update_engine: [0405/081308:INFO:action_processor.cc(121)] ActionProcessor: Aborting processing due to failure.
>
> 04-05 08:13:08.809   643   643 I update_engine: [0405/081308:INFO:update_attempter_android.cc(282)] Processing Done.
>
> 04-05 08:13:08.810   643   643 I update_engine: [0405/081308:INFO:update_attempter_android.cc(302)] Resetting update progress.
>
> 04-05 08:13:08.811  2407  2407 D AMA.ou.UpdateView: Updating progressbar to 0%
>
> 04-05 08:13:08.811  2407  2420 D AMA.ou.Update: onStatusUpdate: status=0, progression=0.0%
>
> 04-05 08:13:08.814  2407  2420 D AMA.ou.Update: onPayloadApplicationComplete: 20
>
> 04-05 08:13:12.348  1033  1033 W WindowManager: Attempted to remove non-existing token: android.os.Binder@ced7efb

Does anyone has any idea what may be the problem ?

Comment: I did a major reformatting of your question. I hope that now it is as easily readable as answerable.

Answer (score 0):

The system img in your device different from the img in PREVIOUS-tardis-target_files.zip, the incremental ota require the device imgs content be same as base target. In other word, you can build the base full ota ptackage with:

```
./build/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files PREVIOUS-tardis-target_files.zip base_full_ota_update.zip
```

update base_full_ota_update.zip at first, reboot, and then update incremental_ota_update.zip, it should be successful.

=-=